# Correct way to access versioned jni so-file on device

Tags: android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, native

I'm having a number of native libraries I cross-compiled on a Linux system for arm64. All files have a version, i.e. a SONAME with a version number in it.

I copied the files and renamed them to e.g. libqdbm.so instead of libqdbm.so.14. I also tried to copy just the link of them with this name.

Linking is working as expected and the `libqdbm.so` the file is added to the APK-file. But when I want to run it on the device, it always searches for the libqdbm.so.14 file and cannot find it.

Of course, I could try to patch it with patchelf, but I think this is not the best way. Also, I don't want to change the make-scripts that unversioned files are built (there are many libraries and I'm really bad in understanding those scripts).

It would be really great if somebody could explain to me, how this is supposed to work? Is there anything I can do? The only other thing which would come in my mind is to change the apk- build-process so that also a versioned so-file is copied, but that also doesn't sound like a good solution.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I now modified some makefiles to build an unversioned library version. Where I could not solve it this way, I used patch-elf tool to patch the SONAME. If someone has a better solution or can explain the best way to do it, feel free.